# Glue Job putting table locks on the sql server as a source

Tags: sql-server, etl, aws-glue

I have a aws-glue job writing csv files in S3 out of SQL server database as source but it is adding table locks on the source database, is there a way to tell the glue job not to put any locks on the sql server database?

The job is a simple python code connecting to the sql server database and writing the the records as CSV files to S3 bucket.

Comment: Can you give the `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint into your SELECT statement when reading? Not sure what your Python looks like so it's hard to suggest.

Comment: That's what i was thinking but there is no parameter available in the aws-glue, `datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database ="xyx", table_name = "abc", transformation_ctx = "datasource0") applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings =[] resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping1, choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2") dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3") datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf[<writes the files to s3>]
`@JNevil